# SQL Query in Form, with order

Tags: sql, forms

I have this query:

```
$query = 'SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Notes, Date FROM CSLogs.dbo.Logs WHERE ForteID = ' . $_GET['ForteID'];
```

It works fine, but I want to add this:

```
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

But the only place I can add it in a sql query when I am in SQL Management Studio is at the end after the Where Statement, but the statement ends at the ' after Where ForteID =.  So adding that the Order By does not works and breaks the code.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$query = 'SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Notes, Date FROM CSLogs.dbo.Logs WHERE ForteID = '.$_GET['ForteID'].' ORDER BY Date DESC';
```

Comment: This is just basic like ABCD, so I suggest that you practice and study more. :)